# How to find all functions in DLL

Tags: ida, disassembly, pe, functions

I'm looking for a way to get the addresses of all the functions in a DLL in the .text section. Is there a way to do it without using a disassembler and moving through the commands? How does IDA know to identify all the functions, even if their start is not the regular "push ebp, mov ebp esp"?

Thanks!

Comment: IDA has plenty of heuristics and IDA knows to infer from a call to a location that the location is a function rather than a label or data. But it's by no means trivial, if your task is to actively avoid any kind of disassembler. So why did you use [tag:ida] and [tag:disassemble] if your task is to *avoid* the obvious tools?

Comment: I'm trying to write a C++ code that does this. I can use a disassembler in code, but it's not powerful enough for that operations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a list of all *exported* functions just by reading the PE headers. But, that won't give you any function names, or expected arguments lists (*), and it won't give you any functions that are internal to the DLL.

In the general case, the only thing you can do is start with exported functions, disassemble from there, follow `jmp`s, and mark everything that's `call`ed as a new function and process it in the same way that you process the exported stuff. This is basically what IDA does.

As C0000022L mentioned, this is in no way trivial, especially with C++ methods that are never called directly, but only through vtable pointers, which is why even IDA gets this kind of stuff *mostly* right, but not *completely* right.

Ida has another feature though, named FLIRT -  it has a database that has signatures of standard library functions for many different compilers. Which is why it can, often, identify standard library function names. But as far as i know, this is a second pass thing; first IDA identifies functions by being called from somewhere, then tries to assign names to those functions using FLIRT. Of course, this helps with standard library functions ONLY, and building this kind of database certainly needs a lot of work as well.

(*) If you're lucky, functions will be exported by name, and if you're very lucky, and the DLL was written in C++, the function name will include the signature. So there are cases when the export list is valuable. But this isn't the generic case, when a function might just be exported by ordinal.

Comment: One more possibility would be debug symbols, if at all available. They often - but not always - contain names of internal functions and other symbols.

Comment: _"But as far as i know, this is a second pass thing..."_ - Correct; FLIRT and FLAIR signatures are only applied after function boundaries have already been identified.